# How to add assets from dependency to local project

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3

My Play! -java project is using another play project (module) as a dependency.
After moving from Play 2.2. to Play 2.3 assets from the sub project are not seen.

In build.sbt I added jar with assets to dependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.company" % "project-sub-module_2.11" % "2.3.3"
  "com.company" % "project-sub-module_2.11" % "2.3.3" artifacts(Artifact("project-sub-module_2.11","asset", "jar", "assets"))
)
```

I can see this jar in dependencies. But its contents seems do not appear in public directory then launching "run" command.

I think I need to add something like
packagedArtifacts in publish:= {
  val artifacts: Map[sbt.Artifact, java.io.File] = (packagedArtifacts in publish).value
  val assets: java.io.File = (playPackageAssets in Compile).value
  artifacts + (Artifact("project-sub-module_2.11", "asset", "jar", "assets") -> assets)
}
but for the compilation process.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@mount_ash is right about using

*"com.company" % "project-sub-module_2.11" % "2.3.3" classifier "assets"*

in your build.sbt to import assets into your project.

On the other hand to publish your assets when compiling, you need to add 
the following to the build.sbt of your modules.

*packagedArtifacts += ((artifact in playPackageAssets).value -> playPackageAssets.value)*

By following these two things I was able to use/discover the assets of my module X in my application host Y.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above problem the code should be like that

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.company" % "project-sub-module_2.11" % "2.3.3"
  "com.company" % "project-sub-module_2.11" % "2.3.3" classifier "assets"
)
```